# setState does not update initialValue of TextFormField widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm totally new to Flutter.
I tried to make a login form with an option to remember the credentials.

Since `SharedPreferences` is async, it makes a this task bit tricky: I created an async method -started in the constructor- to asynchronously obtain the `SharedPreferences` instance, read some values, then call `setState()` writing the new state<sup>1</sup>.

But when `setState()` is called, and the new state written, the UI does not update (i.e. the text fields remain blank).

The `build()` method is something like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  developer.log("build called: rememberCredentials=$rememberCredentials, username=$username, password=$password");
  return (... TextFormField(
    initialValue: username,
    onChanged: (String value) {username = value;}
  ) ...);
}
```

I added a couple of `developer.log()` calls to see when `build()` is called, and if saved preferences are actually read (they do):

```
[log] build called: rememberCredentials=false, username=, password=
[log] read prefs: rememberCredentials=true, username=john, password=1234
[log] build called: rememberCredentials=true, username=john, password=1234
[log] build called: rememberCredentials=true, username=john, password=1234
```

This is the relevant code:

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  String username = "";
  String password = "";
  bool rememberCredentials = false;

  _LoginFormState() {
    readSavedCredentials();
  }

  void readSavedCredentials() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      rememberCredentials = prefs.getBool("rememberCredentials") ?? false;
      username = prefs.getString("username") ?? "";
      password = prefs.getString("password") ?? "";
      developer.log("read prefs: rememberCredentials=$rememberCredentials, username=$username, password=$password");
    });
  }

  void login() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool("rememberCredentials", rememberCredentials);
    await prefs.setString("username", rememberCredentials ? username : "");
    await prefs.setString("password", rememberCredentials ? password : "");
    final resp = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://127.0.0.1:56873/?action=login&user=$username&pass=${md5hex(password)}')
    );
    if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
      Map o = jsonDecode(resp.body);
      if(o["status"] == "AUTH_OK") {
        developer.log(jsonEncode(o));
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FilesView(o["base_url"], o["files"])),
        );
      } else {
        // TODO: report error
      }
    } else {
      // TODO: report error
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    developer.log("build called: rememberCredentials=$rememberCredentials, username=$username, password=$password");
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title())),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextFormField(
                  initialValue: username,
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    username = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Username',
                  )
              )
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextFormField(
                  initialValue: password,
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    password = value;
                  },
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                  )
              )
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 30),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Checkbox(
                    value: rememberCredentials,
                    onChanged: (bool? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        rememberCredentials = value!;
                      });
                    }),
                Text('Remember credentials'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 220,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                login();
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Since I'm totally new to Flutter, I may have made several mistakes. Any advice on the design is very welcome :)

---

<sup>1: another option was to use `FutureBuilder`, but it is messier, and it would delay UI creation... I prefer showing the UI soon, and changing fields values later.</sup>

Comment: Have you tried using await before prefs.getBool() or await prefs.getString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using using the String username to hold your value and onChanged to change it, you can use a text editing controller so

```
String username = '';
```

becomes

```
TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
```

Then in your TextFormFields

```
TextFormField(
  initialValue: username,
  onChanged: (String value) {
    username = value;
  },
  ...
)
```

becomes

```
TextFormField(
  controller: usernameController,
  ...
)
```

Lastly, in your readSavedCredentials() method you can set the text (username) using the text editing controller

```
void readSavedCredentials() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    ...
    usernameController.text = prefs.getString("username") ?? "";
    ...
  });
}
```