# Why doesn't setState rebuild some widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Statefulwidget which is supposed to call Build method when I'm calling the setState:

```
class HtmlEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  const HtmlEditor({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HtmlEditorState();
  }
}

class HtmlEditorState extends State<HtmlEditor> {
  final tags = ["<br>", "<hr>", "<img>", "<b></b>", "<i></i>"];
  final tagButtons = <Widget>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    for (var tag in tags) {
      var button = TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              HtmlState.html += tag;
            });
          },
          child: Text(tag));
      tagButtons.add(button);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ButtonBar(
          children: tagButtons,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: HtmlState.html,
                maxLines: 100,
                onChanged: (value) => HtmlState.html = value)),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Text("Length: ${HtmlState.html.length}")),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 50.0),
          child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(1);
              },
              child: const Text("See Results")),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class HtmlState {
  static String html = "<font color='red'> Hello <font>";
}
```

But After pressing the one of the tag buttons TextFormField doesn't update it's initial value :

```
 Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: HtmlState.html,
                maxLines: 100,
                onChanged: (value) => HtmlState.html = value)),
```

While this part is updated :

```
     Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Text("Length: ${HtmlState.html.length}")),
```

I know this initialValue is supposed to be set once but as we know Flutter's UI is declarative so every time I call setState TextFormField should be created with the new initialValue right?
So what's the problem here?
Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState does not update TextFormField when use initialValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053956/setstate-does-not-update-textformfield-when-use-initialvalue)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859732/setstate-does-not-update-initialvalue-of-textformfield-widgets

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
HtmlState.html += tag;
```

the `HtmlState` reference remains the same, so the widget that use it, don't think it has been changed and doesn't refresh. You have 2 options:
use

```
HtmlState.html = HtmlState.html + tag;
```

but here, maybe is better not to use a static for the `String html`.

Or use `key: UniqueKey(),` on those widgets that use `HtmlState.html`